# after windows task scheduler, browser is left in memory

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

On Windows 2008...  I have 3 daily scheduled tasks, each that point to a browser .exe, with a URL as a parameter.  The tasks run fine, but afterwards, each task has a leftover instance of the browser left in memory.  So after a few days, there are more and more in memory, unless I login to clear them out.

I tried both chrome.exe and iexplore.exe, and also a calling a batch file with "start http://....", but all give the same results.

Is there a way to schedule a URL to run, but have the browser clear itself out of memory afterwards?

Or do I need to add another scheduled process to kill the previous processes?

Thanks.

Comment: Be clear, the window to the browser is closed?  but the task itself remains? Or is this an issue of what or who is going to close the opened browser item?

Comment: After the task is run, the browser process remains listed in the task manager, once for each task executed.  I need to get these cleared out before eat up all available memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, create a second batch file which kills all references to the browser(s) and run it at a different point.

```
taskkill /im iexplorer.exe
taskkill /im firefox.exe
```

So, task manager does your task at 9am, then at 9:30am, the above is ran!

I don't think you can do this with 1 command (if it's a batch) as it there is no indication that each 'task' is complete; Meaning, it will probably load the browser (as per your question) but the close command will occur before the site is actually downloaded.

Comment: Still not clear what ray is doing, but for the batch in win7 there is a timeout command possible . >timeout /T 1  In XP we had to use a 3rd party sleep cmd. (both are not cpu hogging loops) .  Task scheduler also has a "Stop the task if it runs longer than" and you can type in #minutes. It is in "settings" tab  If that helps.

Comment: The "Stop the task if it runs longer than" checkbox did it.  After a couple of days, the processes are no longer accumulating.  Thanks.